# How NOT to create a new textfield if one textfield has been added to the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm using the following code to create the textfield in a UITableView Cell:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.showsReorderControl = YES;
}

if (indexPath.row == 1)
{
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,10,260,40)];
    textField.placeholder = @"Activity 1:  Type Name";
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.clearButtonMode = YES;
    [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [cell addSubview:textField];
}

return cell;
```

I'm creating 3 textFields the exact same way.  The only difference is the placeHolder text.

When the keyboard pops up, the view scrolls up and the textField 1 goes off the screen.  Upon return, I think the textField is being recreated.

Below are some screen shots:

First time appearance of the cell (looks great):

[image]

Returns after being scrolled off the screen (notice the first textfield):
[image]

In cell one, when I start typing, the 2nd created textField's placeHolder disappears, but the first textField's Placeholder remains:

[image]

Two questions:

1. How do I avoid recreating textField in the cell? or eliminate this problem?
2. When recreated, why is textField from Cell 3 with placeHolder of "Activity 3: Type Name" appears on cell one textField?

Comment: It's not a 3, it's a 3 and a 1 overlapped. Does this suggest you anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming this code is in the `cellForRow` tableview dataSource protocol method. The problem is that this method is called multiple times (sometimes when you wouldn't expect), causing a new text field to be created and added to the same cell. In order to resolve this issue **you need to add a text field only when the cell is created**, and then configure the cells each time the method is called. I would recommend creating a table cell subclass, but you can change your code to this for learning purposes:

```
#define kTextFieldTag 1

UITextField* textField = [cell viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.showsReorderControl = YES;

    /* only called when cell is created */
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,10,260,40)];
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.clearButtonMode = YES;
    textField.tag = kTextFieldTag; /* I would recommend a cell subclass with a textfield member over the tag method in real code*/
    [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [cell addSubview:textField];
}

/* called whenever cell content needs to be updated */
if (indexPath.row == 1)
{
   textField.placeholder = @"Activity 1:  Type Name";
}
...
/* or replace if checks with with: */
textField.placeholder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Activity %i: Type Name", (int)indexPath.row]; /* Handles all fields :) */
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend you check out the free [Sensible TableView](http://sensiblecocoa.com) framework. The framework not only automatically creates the input cells for you, but will also auto apply the changes back to your objects. Highly recommended and saves me tons of time.